# Align label to right in gtk.table

Tags: c#, mono, alignment, label, gtk#

I'm developing a application that write by C# and GTK# on Mono platform,
but I get into trouble of how to align label to right in table.

Code segment:

```
var tblMsgBody = new Table(4, 2, false);
var lblSpeed = new Label("Speed:");
lblSpeed.Justify = Justification.Right;
tblMsgBody.Attach(lblSpeed, 0, 1, 1, 2);
```

But whatever I change the properties of table/label, the label always in the center of table cell.
Appreciate if anyone could do me a favor.